# Styling No file chosen message in input type file

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<input type="file" class="brows-down">
```

In input type file "No file chosen" text display in front of browse button. But I want to display this text below the browse button. Any possible solution?

Comment: @BeatAlex Please read the question. You are wrong. That's how to style the `button` NOT the `label`...

Comment: You're right @BramDriesen, I skim read and totally missed that out. My apologies!

Comment: please refer this http://www.abeautifulsite.net/whipping-file-inputs-into-shape-with-bootstrap-3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.left {
    float: left;
}

.both {
    clear: both;
}

.file-upload-container {
    width:400px;
    border: 1px solid #efefef;
    padding:10px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px;
    background: #fbfbfa;
}

.file-upload-override-button {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color:#79bbff;
}

.file-upload-override-button:hover {
    background-color:#378de5;
}

.file-upload-override-button:active {
    position:relative; top:1px;
}

.file-upload-button {
    position: absolute;
    height: 50px;
    top: -10px;
    left: -10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 0;
    filter:alpha(opacity=0);
}

.file-upload-filename {
    margin-top: 10px;
    height: auto;
    clear:both;
    float:left
}
```

```html
<div class="file-upload-container">
    <div class="file-upload-override-button left">
        Choose file
        <input type="file" class="file-upload-button" id="file-upload-button"/>
    </div>
    <div class="file-upload-filename left" id="file-upload-filename">No file selected</div>
    <div class="both"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
window.pressed = function(){
    var a = document.getElementById('aa');
    if(a.value == "")
    {
        fileLabel.innerHTML = "No File Selected";
    }
    else
    {
        var theSplit = a.value.split('\\');
        fileLabel.innerHTML = theSplit[theSplit.length-1];
    }
};
```

```css
input[type=file]{
    width:90px;
    color:transparent;
}
label{
    display:block;
}
```

```html
<div><input type='file' title="Choose a video please" id="aa" onchange="pressed()"><label id="fileLabel">No File Selected</label></div>
```